# How to make it so only the labels show up as points on a scatter plot in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am trying to plot countries on a graph in excel using two letter codes, but the points keep getting in the way and cluttering the graph! Is there any way to remove them and only keep the labels?

I would try it in R but I would like to be able to reposition them by hand in case they overlap.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Bear in mind that the point is what is precisely placed on the chart, the label is, at best, placed close to the point.  You can't replace the point with the label.  If the labels are being consistent placed with some offset from the point, you may be able to improve the label placement by adjusting the data to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

1. Open the format toolbar (select graph and hit CTRL+1)
2. Select a point on the graph
3. on the format toolbar select the fill and line button (the paint can dumping paint)
4. select the "marker" button
5. select the "no fill" radio button under the "fill" list and the "no line" radio button under the "border" list